# Iterating to produce a unique list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, char, unique

This is the initial code:

```
word_list = ['cat','dog','rabbit']
letter_list = [ ]
for a_word in word_list:
   for a_letter in a_word:
      letter_list.append(a_letter)
print(letter_list)
```

I need to modify it to produce a list of unique letters.

Could somebody please advise how to do this **without using set()**

The result should be like this

```
> ['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'b', 'i']
```

Comment: What is the problem with set? Is there any restriction? You can use [numpy unique](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html)

Comment: Without a set or something close to it, you get a complexity of O(n^2) instead of O(n), which is much worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only problem that I can see is that you have not checked if the letter is already present in list or not. Try this:

```
>>> word_list= ['cat', 'dog', 'rabbit']
>>> letter_list= []
>>> for a_word in word_list:
    for a_letter in a_word:
        if a_letter not in letter_list:
            letter_list.append(a_letter)


>>> print letter_list
['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'b', 'i']
```

Comment: how would i do this without using a function?

Comment: Edited my answer. Please check. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
>>> word_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'rabbit']
>>> chars = [char for word in word_list for char in list(word)] # combine all chars
>>> letter_list = [ii for n, ii in enumerate(chars) if ii not in chars[:n]] # remove duplicated chars
>>>
>>> print letter_list
['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'b', 'i']
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just place this condition : `if a_letter not in letter_list` after the second for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary, it is optimized for key based random look-ups. Keep the value as 1 if the key is encountered. Finally, extract all the keys at the end.

```
unique_chars = {}
word_list = ['cat','dog','rabbit']
for word in word_list:
    for alph in word:
        unique_chars[alph] = 1 #or any other value
letter_list = unique_chars.keys()
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add a condition :

```
if a_letter not in letter_list
```

And add the `a_letter` is not in the `letter_list`

The code is as follows :

```
word_list = ['cat','dog','rabbit']
letter_list = []

for a_word in word_list:
   for a_letter in a_word:
      if a_letter not in letter_list
        letter_list.append(a_letter)

print(letter_list)
```

The output for this would be :

```
['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'b', 'i']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li = [char for word in word_list for char in word] # create list with individual characters
li_without_duplicates = list(dict.fromkeys(li)) #remove duplicates
print(li_without_duplicates)
```